# JSON Generation with "type": ["null", "string"],"

Tags: java, json, avro

Trying to generate a json following an avro schema. One of the elements is this:

```
{
  "name": "myNumber",
  "type": ["null", "string"],
  "default": null
},
```

I have generated the json with this field:

```
"myNumber": {
    "string": "1460257"
},
```

but when I do this and attempt to convert it to an avro file to post to kafka (using apache avro library), I get this error:

```
Expected Unknown fields: [myNumber]. Got END_ARRAY
```

Is something wrong with the way I am creating this field in the JSON? Everything else is working fine besides this, which throws an error

Comment: You need to share some code.

Comment: add code how you are attemping to convert to avro file...

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the avro schema i was basing my generation off was different to the schema found in kafka